# How to add number of records per page filter in views

Tags: 7, views

I want to add a filter to customize the number of records to be show on per page in views.

Can anyone assist me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

You can add items per page filter from pager option views

Views->pager options->EXPOSED OPTIONS